# Dataframe when converted to numpy array gives float values with more decimal places

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe as so:

[image]

and the datatypes are as follows:

[image]

When I convert the dataframe to a numpy array, the result looks like this:
[image]

Why does this happen?
if I convert the dtypes of all the columns to the same dtype by :

```
df = df.astype('float64')
```

then the result looks fine, but why does this happen?

Comment: How did you convert the dataframe to a numpy array?

Answer (score 0):

Reason if [float precision problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/455634/2901002), possible solution should be `Decimal` if precision is important:

```
from decimal import Decimal

df = df.astype('float64').applymap(Decimal)
```